# I want to Understand - URL Parameter Showing me different prices

Tags: url, url-parameters

Please help me understand how this is happening:

I am monitoring one of my competitor's website products. But something strange happened and I am bit confused how this is possible.

Please see the urls below which leads to same product but showing me different prices.

https://www.werko.com.au/product/genuine-fuji-xerox-cwaa0751-waste-toner-bottle/

Price - $33.00

https://www.werko.com.au/product/genuine-fuji-xerox-cwaa0751-waste-toner-bottle/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5unSyImD3wIVRBSPCh2y3QNcEAsYASABEgJBpvD_BwE

Price - $31.57

If "?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5unSyImD3wIVRBSPCh2y3QNcEAsYAS ABEgJBpvD_BwE" portion is of URL is added to any product URL it will show me the edited prices otherwise the old prices. How this is happening?

Comment: Seems a typical google tracking code.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a GET parameter ([Query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)) and the webpage is generated (on the server by the script) depending on it. The value itself (part after =) is just a random string here.
**Edit:** actually it's the [Google Click ID](https://support.google.com/searchads/answer/7342044?hl=en) which they *also* use to change the price. So if the Click ID is present, the price is lowered.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jack!! This will certainly help me understand this issue...